# can i store data in the form of json object in mysql database through java?

Tags: java, mysql

i am making an attendance management application in java and i am facing  a problem in making its database schema i want to store the attendance and show it month wise and semester wise.
i decided the following schema :

```
STUDENTS(name,class,roll... ) table , 
ATTENDANCE(rollNo , attendanceStatus , date) table , 
SUBJECTS(class , subject, subId...) table.
```

but the problem arises here is that if i have to take the attendance of a class which have 50 students and 5 subject lectures daily so total rows added in the attendance table every day are 50x5 so my table will grow very much !

is this a wrong approach or it is ok ? 
i wonder if i can store attendance of one lecture as some object like json object ? is it possible to store json oject in mysql database ?

Comment: why you're adding rows for attendance ? you can simply use counter in your database to keep track of student's present number of days

Comment: OP might want to keep track of when a student was absent, rather than whether the student missed any classes.

Comment: i can use counter but then i will not be able to display attendance month wise and semester wise Onkar Musale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but that would defeat the purpose of having a good database design.

I would recommend the following schema, assuming a student can only attend or miss a class (2 states):

Student(**student_id**, name) 
Class(**class_id**, class_name) 
Enrollment(**enrollment_id**, student_id, class_id) 
Absence(**enrollment_id**, **date**)

This way, you can assume that if the student isn't in the `Absence` table on that date, they attended the class. The reason to record absences rather than attendances is that students are more likely to attend class than miss class, which means the `Absence` table will not grow as fast as an "Attendance" table.

Comment: yup i understood what you wanna say ! is it ok to use  a  string  of 50 characters to represent attendance ??  with your idea will i be able to query data according to the date like month wise and semester(6 months ) wise 
 ??

Comment: If you use a string of 50 characters to represent attendance, it becomes unclear which character is which student, especially if you have different students all the time.

Yes, you will be able to query data according to the date. For example, `SELECT * FROM Absence WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-06-30'` will get a list of all the absences between Jan 1 and Jun 30, inclusive.

Comment: Should i store roll numbers of absenties in  a string ?? this will reduce the number of rows like 3 students are absent then 3 rows will be added and i is use my method one row will be added for as many as students absent ! with your method if all are present then ?? but with my method i can add null in string??

Comment: The `Absence` table is now very small (12 bytes / row) which means you can store about `90,000,000` absences in 1 gigabyte, which is very good. If you use a string, you can't tell exactly which student was missing. If everybody is present, then you don't insert anything in the table. Because nothing is in the table on that day, you know that everyone was present.